# What are the risks of using NOLOCK when knowing the selected rows aren't being modified?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with ~700k registries which holds data from various countries and is suffering occasional deadlocks.

I can have transactions selecting data from the table from a specific country, while other transactions may be writing data of another country. But there can never be a read/write of the same country happening at once.

Am I right to think using NOLOCK would be ok in this particular scenario? Could there be any risks?

Comment: Tag the specific dbms. NOLOCK is product specific.

Comment: Instead of dealing with the symptom (deadlock) by using a query hint you should find and fix the source of the problem.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is OK if you don't care about getting wrong results (for example, a monitoring query that will be repeated 10 seconds from now anyway, and can tolerate a bad outcome). For anything else, just say no. Snapshot isolation is one alternative; *increasing* locking to prevent the kind of lock acquire inversion that causes deadlocks is another. "I'm not modifying this row so `NOLOCK` should be OK" is not, for the reasons Luaan has given in the answer. `NOLOCK` can duplicate rows and skip rows under load by way of page movements; it doesn't care about row-by-row modifications.

Comment: It's important to note that you can get duplicate rows and skip rows under default `READ COMMITTED` too; not just under `NOLOCK`. When scanning a table, locks are only acquired as you read the row, and released when you are done reading that row. Now imagine that the row you *just* read is modified, and its clustering moves it to the end of the table. When you scan reaches the end of the table you will read the same row again. This is what `REPEATABLE READ` was invented for - you hold locks on rows after you've read them. And if you want to avoid missing rows entirely: you need `SERIALIZABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking too high-level. NOLOCK is a low-level hint. Just because one record is for country A and another for country B doesn't mean that they aren't e.g. on the same data page; or their indices aren't on the same data page. You're still exposed to the same risks when you update country B as if you were updating country A. You still get dirty reads, you still get duplicate and missing records, the whole shebang. There might be certain mitigation options (table partitioning, perhaps?), but I'm not knowledgeable enough to answer that well.